# Born in Eastern Europe - what am I?

Tags: riddle

Here is my first riddle. I hope it will make sense because English is not my first language. I hope you'll enjoy it.

> I was born in Eastern Europe, but none can say when exactly
>   My history is filled by mysteries and legends
>   I became French to rule the world
>
> I am raised by men early in the morning
>   Layer after layer they build my core
>
> Sometime, you can see me in the sky
>   But don't mistake me with antelope horns

Comment: "I am raised by men early in the morning" I don't want to comment this ahah!

Comment: I did not think of that :)

Comment: Great first riddle! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is

> Croissant

I was born in Eastern Europe, but none can say when exactly

> Some claim that it's from Buda (Hungary).

My history is filled by mysteries and legends

> Nobody knows who invented it, there are many [legends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croissant)

I became French to rule the world

> It's now considered a typical French food.

I am raised by men early in the morning

> Most people eat it in the morning

Layer after layer they build my core

> It's made of several layers

Sometime, you can see me in the sky

> Half-moon

But don't mistake me with antelope horns

> Similar shape

Comment: For the antelope horns, I was refering to [this](http://moroccanfood.about.com/od/dessertsandcookies/r/kaab_el_ghazal_gazelle_horns.htm)

Comment: Ah, great, never heard of that dish before! Nice riddle anyway :)

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be too easy though

Comment: @A.D. At first the "layer after layer" made me think about kebab, while "French" suggested french fries. Finally, I decided to google some French foods and my eye went on croissant

Comment: @A.D. I'd say the last verse is the biggest giveaway.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's the [croissant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croissant) (in the shape of a half moon).

Comment: That's correct. But you did not explain the clues.

Comment: @A.D. Where can I learn about the expected format of answers. I'm completely new to the site. BTW, I would have guessed that "raised by men ..." refers to the baker's job.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/) and by reading other posts

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! You can get information also here: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Drux I was thinking of the baker's job indeed

Comment: @leoll2 Thx for the link. (The linked document does not mention clues -- perhaps time for an update.)

Comment: In Puzzling is common habit to explain our answers in order to avoid low-quality posts :)

Comment: @leoll2 "common habit", oh well ...